# Why input event for value EU citizen does not work

Tags: javascript

[Input not working ][1]

I added an event with the goal of listening to an event when the value of the input is EU citizen so I added it on the button with id 'submit' 
The function does work but when I write EU citizen in the input the message 'You are eligible should show' but nothing happens.

```
//1. Listen for submit buttton for Nationality 
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();


})

//UI vars for Nationality 

const nationality = document.getElementById('submit')

//show message you are eligible if it evaluates to EU citizen 

function checkNationality(input) {
if(input === 'EU citizen') {

    console.log('You are eligible')

} else {

  console.log('You are not eligible')

}
}
```

What am I missing? help, please

Comment: please add your HTML,JS code with the snippet.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Strongly suggest you spend some time reading [ask] and how to create a [mcve] so that you are able to link your problem descrition with the relevant code in order for us to help

Comment: Thanks! I have added the code in the proper way:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not posted the full code. Thinking about what you are trying to achieve , please see the code below:

```
<input type="text" id="data"/>
<button id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getData();">Submit</button>

function getData(){
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("data").value;
  //console.log(inputVal);
  if(inputVal === "EU citizen"){
    console.log("You are eligible");
  } else {
    console.log("You are not eligible");
  }

}
```

Comment: I have added the code:)

Comment: That is great! If all is well, can I ask for an upvote ? Happy learning!

Comment: Sure I am happy to give you an upvote but because I am not yet an old user I cant:( it returns a message about the reputation scores

Comment: Ok , got it . I am not sure if there is an option to accept the answer(a tick mark)  or not also . Thank you for reverting back !

Comment: Added a tick mark :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```js
var nationalityElement = document.querySelector("select");
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  if(nationalityElement.value === "EU") {
    console.log("You are eligible");
  }else {
    console.log("You are not eligible");
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Nationality</label><br>
<select>
  <option value="AU">AU</option>
  <option value="EU">EU</option>
  <option value="US">US</option>
  <option value="AS">AS</option>
  <option value="AF">AF</option>
</select><br>
<button>Submit Nationality status</button>
```